# Match and replace every 7th instance of a <td> tag

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm struggling to wrap my head around how to get this regex working in Visual Studio Code.

I'm trying to match every 7th instance of `<td>` tag to then replace it with `<td data-order="">`.

**Original**

```
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Owner</td>
<td>Value</td>
<td>Total</td>
<td>Percent</td>
<td>Ratio</td>
<td>Final</td>
</tr>
```

**What I want**

```
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Owner</td>
<td>Value</td>
<td>Total</td>
<td>Percent</td>
<td data-order="">Ratio</td>
<td>Final</td>
</tr>
```

I've tried variations on `((?:.*<td>){1})`, but any number greater than 1 just gives me a "No results" message.

Comment: This is not clear: should the 7th `<td>`  be inside the same `<tr>` and table? What is `((?:.*<td>){1})` supposed to match? This is clearly not matching any seventh `td`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You say "match every 7th instance" but I think you mean match the seventh instance, not the 7th, 14th, 21st, etc.  Assuming that you mean the 7th only..."]

If your data is really as regular and structured as you showed, you could use this as the regex in a **Find**

Find: `(?<=<tr>\n(?:<td>.*<\/td>\n){6})(<td)`
Replace: `<td data-order=""`

If you might have newlines within a `<td>...\n...</td>` tag, use this

Find: `(?<=<tr>\n(?:<td>[^/]*<\/td>\n){6})(<td)`
Replace: `<td data-order=""`

Vscode's find/replace (in one file) can use a non-fixed length lookbehind like

`(?<=<tr>\n(?:<td>.*<\/td>\n){6})`

The search across files cannot do that so this regex would not work there.  Also sites like regex101.com can't use it either so I'll show a demo in vscode itself:

[image: every seventh td demo]

Comment: This is the answer, thank you Mark. I had been playing around in regex101.com and realized it functioned differently than VS Code. Your GIF was also a great help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#move-by). And use the command `moveby.regex`.

In your `keybindings.json` define a keybinding to search for the next `<td>` tag.

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i ctrl+u",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.regex",
    "args": {
      "regex": "<td[^>]*>",
      "properties": ["next", "end"]
    }
  }
```

1. Select the first `<tr>` tag of where you want to start
2. Select every following `<tr>` tag with:

   - command: **Add Selection to Next Find Match**
     (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - `editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch`)
   - menu option: **Selection** > **Select All Occurrences**
3. Apply the key binding as many times as you want
4. Your cursors are now after the n-th `<td>` tag
5. Make any edits you want
6. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave Multi Cursor mode

In [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#move-by) v1.2.0 you can specify a repeat count. The count can be fixed or asked from the user.

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i ctrl+u",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.regex",
    "args": {
      "regex": "<td[^>]*>",
      "properties": ["next", "end"],
      "repeat": "ask"
    }
  }
```

If you leave out the property `"regex"` you are asked for a regular expression too.

**Edit**

Using a regular expression takes quite some time to get it correct

```js
let testStr =`<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Owner</td>
<td>Value</td>
<td>Total</td>
<td>Percent</td>
<td>Ratio</td>
<td>Final</td>
</tr>`;

var replace = '$1<td class="red">$2';
var regex = new RegExp("(<tr>[\n\r\s]*(?:<td[^>]*>(?:.|[\n\r\s])*?</td>[\n\r\s]*){6})<td>((?:.|[\n\r\s])*</tr>)");
var newstr=testStr.replace(regex,replace);
console.log(newstr);

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=newstr
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody  >
  <tr id="test">
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh wow that RegExp... Why did I even try :(

Comment: @ikiK The possible newlines makes it more complicated and some regexp engines interpret the capture groups different, it could be that VSC does it a bit different and you can use `[\r\n\s\S]`, but SO needed it a bit different

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in this as I don't know much of regex and need to learn, but I manged to make it so in two goes.

I hope someone will correct me and help with correct one way.

I tried to folow this: but cant make it to work: [Find Nth Occurrence of Character](https://www.reddit.com/r/regex/comments/8dbmla/find_nth_occurrence_of_character_in_each_row/)

```js
let testStr = '<td>1</td><td>Name</td><td>Owner</td><td>Value</td><td>Total</td><td>Percent</td><td>Ratio</td><td>Final</td>';

var replace = '<td class="red">';
var regex = new RegExp("((<td>.*?)){7}");
// tried with a lot of (?:...) combinations here but none works :(
var newstr=testStr.replace(regex,replace);

var regex2 = new RegExp("((</td>.*?)){6}");
var newstr2=testStr.match(regex2);

console.log(newstr);
console.log(newstr2[0]);

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=newstr2[0]+newstr
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody  >
  <tr id="test">
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**
Got something :)

```js
let testStr = '<td>1</td><td>Name</td><td>Owner</td><td>Value</td><td>Total</td><td>Percent</td><td>Ratio</td><td>Final</td>';

var replace = '<td class="red">';
var regex = new RegExp("(?:[</td>]){6}(<td>)");
var newstr=testStr.replace(regex,replace);

console.log(newstr);

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=newstr
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody  >
  <tr id="test">
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And with **@rioV8's** help:

```js
let testStr = '<td>1</td><td>Name</td><td>Owner</td><td>Value</td><td>Total</td><td>Percent</td><td>Ratio</td><td>Final</td>';

var replace = '$1<td class="red">';
var regex = new RegExp("((?:.*?</td>){6})<td>");
var newstr=testStr.replace(regex,replace);

console.log(newstr);

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=newstr
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody  >
  <tr id="test">
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this will fail if the table has 20 columns, and you have to take into account that there could be newline chars inbetween `<td>` tags

Comment: @rioV8 Like I mentioned, I dont know what im doing ;)  But, how come fail after 20 columns? Both of those RegExp's count from start?  And new lines could be ignored?

Comment: OP asked **every** 7th `td` tag, for all rows of the table, you don't start at the `tr` tag so `td` tag 14 on the row will also be changed, for all rows you have to do a **global** search replace

Comment: what is the use of `.*?`, there is nothing after that so it will match 0 characters, the default repeat of a group is `{1}` so that is also redundant

Comment: @rioV8 Yeah i noticed that, but can you please explain how come the last `t` in `Percent` got lost? Its driving me crazy.

Comment: Because you use the regexp `[</td>]{6}`, this is a character class, the string `t</td>` matches, you got lucky the word `Percent` ends in a `t` any other letter and you would not have a match, use the regex `((?:.*?</td>){6})<td>` and replace string `$1<td class="red">`

Comment: @rioV8 Oh wow thanks a lot, I Thing I get it now how this works! So dont use anything before 6th `</td>` then take next `<td>`, replace it with given string, that gives replacement plus the rest, and attached  `$1` will give me `the don't use part`, awesome.  I appreciate the help.